Tell apscheduler to not log the maximum number of instances reached message
I'm using apscheduler to deal with several jobs that run asyncronously. One of those tasks requests some payload from an API every second. Due to how the network works the job can await for 10 seconds before being aborted. While the job is being run apscheduler displays several warnings in the log telling me that the maximum number of running instances was reached, adding more instances would not make the job run faster (or better).
How do I tell apscheduler to stop logging that type of message for that job?
The following code reproduces the problem.
import asyncio
import logging

from apscheduler.executors.pool import ThreadPoolExecutor
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler


async def my_slow_job():
    await asyncio.sleep(10)


async def main():
    logging.basicConfig(
        format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",
        level=logging.INFO,
    )
    scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler(
        executor=ThreadPoolExecutor(),
        job_defaults={'trigger': 'interval', 'seconds': 1, 'max_instances': 1}
    )
    scheduler.add_job(my_slow_job, 'interval')
    scheduler.start()
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1000)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit, asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError):
        logging.warning("Shutting down by user request")



I assume you have read https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/userguide.html#troubleshooting.  It appears that apscheduler uses the basic Python logging features, which allows you to configure the logger any way you want.  You can filter out messages as desired.  See https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.filter.
